# Flash player Show All, set up for air application

Tags: flash, air, scalability

I have flash application (*.swf).If run it in FlashPlayer I can go to the menu View->Show All (check). After it my flash application will be scalable, I can resize with saving general view of application. So, My Question is, How can I set up the same from **code** for the air application ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```